# Android Studio Emulator does not start my apk with 1.2GB mp3 files

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

Well...

I'm trying to create a apk using android studio. But when i put 1189 files in mp3 to folder assets or raw in android studio, the android studio emulator does not start my apk.

If i delete 1180 files, for example, and try to run, my apk is started normally. I created a Virtual Devices with 2GB RAM, 3GB internal and 100MB SDcard.

Can anyone help me to fix this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solition is:

https://www.genymotion.com/

With a virtual machine, may app for test working.